# How do I configure an Excel file as a Linked Server in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, excel, linked-server

I have opened the Linked Server dialog to create a Linked Server so that I can import my excel file data to a SQL Server 2005 database. Which provider must I use and what other settings do I need to fill in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would set it up using either OLEDB provider or the provider for ODBC drivers and create a connection using the ODBC Administrator tool on the server to the Excel file. Are you planning to read from this Excel file on a regular basis? If not, then setting it up as a Linked Server could be overkill.

For more details, see "[How to import data from Excel to SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686)" and "[How to use Excel with SQL Server linked servers and distributed queries](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306397/EN-US)"

Answer (score 3):

For those who are using SQL SERVER 2012+ you can use the Microsoft OLEDB 12.0 Provider that comes with SQL Server 2012+ and which allows you to use Excel 2007-2013 xlsx files for adhoc distributed queries or as a linked server. Examples below.

The Excel workbook 'Application.xlsx' has 3 worksheets Application,Device,User
First Activate Ad Hoc Queries on the Server.

```
USE MSDB
GO
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OverRide
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OverRide
GO

EXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'AllowInProcess' , 1
GO

EXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'DynamicParameters' , 1
```

For Ad Hoc Queries use the OPENROWSET Function.

```
SELECT * FROM 
OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel   8.0;Database=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Application.xlsx;HDR=YES', 'SELECT * FROM [Application$]');

SELECT * FROM 
OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel   8.0;Database=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Application.xlsx;HDR=YES', 'SELECT * FROM [Device$]');

SELECT * FROM 
OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel  8.0;Database=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Application.xlsx;HDR=YES', 'SELECT * FROM [User$]');
```

For Creating a Linked Server for Excel 2007-2013 format:

```
USE MSDB
GO
EXEC sp_addLinkedServer
@server= 'XLSX_MATRIX',
@srvproduct = 'ACE 12.0',
@provider = 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
@datasrc = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Application.xlsx',
@provstr = 'Excel 12.0; HDR=Yes'
```

Now, query your excel file in two ways:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (XLSX_MATRIX, 'Select * from [Application$]')
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (XLSX_MATRIX, 'Select * from [Device$]')
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (XLSX_MATRIX, 'Select * from [User$]')

SELECT * FROM XLSX_MATRIX...[Application$]
SELECT * FROM XLSX_MATRIX...[Device$]
SELECT * FROM XLSX_MATRIX...[User$]
```

Comment: Amazing answer. Definitively should be the accepted one.

Two things to add:

1. If your excel filepath contains spaces, you do *NOT* need to add any extra quote marks. Just let the spaces be.

2. Make sure that the names of your excel sheets match when you call openrowset adhocs.